Equivalence between two different definition of right derivative
It's probably obvious (and I think it is too). Today I was giving lesson about derivatives and when I defined the concept of right and left derivative, the following doubt arose in my mind.
I said that a continuous function $f:D\to \mathbb{R}$, which is supposed to be differentiable in $D^\circ$, is right differentiable in $x_0\in D^\circ$ iff exists
$$\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}=f_+'(x_0)\in \mathbb{R}$$

But, doing an example, it seemed natural (and faster) to me to calculate  $$\lim_{x\to x_0^+}f'(x)$$ instead.
The example was to prove that $f(x)=|x-1|$ is not differentiable in $x=1$.
The derivative is $$f'(x)=\begin{cases}1, & x>1 \\ -1, & x<1\end{cases}$$ For $x=1$, doing $\lim_{x\to 1^+}f'(x)$ is equivalent to apply the definition of right derivative.
Indeed, the result are the same and so I tried to prove
$$\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}=\lim_{x\to x_0^+}f'(x)$$
Starting to the RHS, I have that:
$$\lim_{x\to x_0^+}f'(x)=\lim_{x\to x_0^+}\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0^+}\lim_{x\to x_0^+}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}$$
using the fact that $f$ is continuous (because is differentiable).
Is this a valid poof? Is the switch between the two limits allowed? Is there a easier way to see the equivalence? Thanks!

@EricM.Schmidt The linked question asks for the difference between a differentiable function and a continuously differentiable function. The question above asks something about a continuous function that is differentiable everywhere except for a single point and if the fact, that the derivative can be continuously extended implies that the function is differentiable everywhere.

Well the exchange of the limits can a posteriori be justified. You can use L'Hopitals rule for a quick proof. Alternatively use the mean value theorem as follows:
Let $f\colon [a,b)\to \mathbb R$ for $a<b$ be a continuous function that is differentiable on $(a,b)$. For any $x\in (a,b)$ the mean value theorem yields a $\xi_x\in (a,x)$ such that
$$
f(x)-f(a)=f'(\xi_x)(x-a).
$$
For $x\to a$ we have $\xi_x\to a$ and therefore
$$
\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=\lim_{x\to a} f'(\xi_x)=\lim_{x\to a} f'(x)
$$
provided that the limit of $f'$ exists.
However the converse of course does not have to be true. A function can be (left/right) differentiable at a point while the corresponding limit of the derivative may fail to even exist.

Okay, it looks good to me. But, the argument holds because we know that the derivative (as a function) exists at least in a neighborhood of $x_0$?

Yes, in order for this argument to apply to your situation it is necessary that your $f$ is differentiable at least on some interval of the form $(x_0,b)$ for $b>x_0$.
